# How to properly use partial views and modal in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to angularjs so maybe I am not using things properly, please guide me for right approach.

So here is my scenario:

I have two objects Books and author I have wrote separate controllers for both with CRUD actions and different views for each action and they all are working good.

From Author’s “Add” view there is select box for Books so that user can select a book and add new author and associate that author with selected book.

Now the problem is that I need to add “Add a new book” button in Author’s “Add” view which will open a Book’s “Add” view in modal so that user can add new book which would be automatically added to Author’s “Add” form’s select box and get selected .

As I have already created controller,actions and views for Book’s CRUD, so I want to reuse Book’s “Add” action and view.

While searching through internet I came across “Angularjs ui bootstrap” and I decided to use it and in order to implement it I created partial view for Book’s Add view.

Here is my implementation:

Controllers.js:

```
myapp.controller('AuthorController', ['$scope',. . .,'$uibModal',
 function ($scope,. . ,$uibModal) {
$scope.open = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller:’BookController’,
          size: size,

        });
    }
});
```

BookController:

```
$scope.AddNew=function(){
        if($scope.book.id>0){
            Book.update({id:$scope.book.id},$scope.book,function(data){
                $location.path('/books');
        });
        }
        else{
            Book.save($scope.book,function(data){
                $location.path('/books');
            });
        }
    };
```

Author Add view:

```
<button class="btn btn-info create" ng-click="open()">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add a new Book</button>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div ng-include src="'./resources/views/Book/_details.html'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="AddNew()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

This code is working that it adds new book by calling Book’s  “AddNew” function which adds a new book and redirects to book list but in case of calling from Author’s controller I need it to just add new book and let the AuthorController know that new book has been added and return new book’s id.

How can I let the AuthorController know about new book?

Please guide me.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Your BookController needs to return to AuthorController by closing the $uibModalInstance like this:

```
$scope.AddNew=function(){
    var isNew;
    if($scope.book.id>0){
        Book.update({id:$scope.book.id},$scope.book,function(data){
            isNew = false;
    });
    }
    else{
        Book.save($scope.book,function(data){
            isNew = true;
        });
    $uibModalInstance.close({bookId: $scope.book.id, isNew: isNew}); 
    }
};
```

Then your AuthorController would handle the return like this:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function(result) { 
    if(result.isNew){
                // stay here
            }else{
                // redirect to book                    
            }
});
```

Comment: but how can i differentiate that the call is from BookController or AuthorController as I need to redirect to book list page when call coming from BookController?

Comment: My approach is to always close the modal using $uibModalInstance.close() and handle any subsequent logic for your redirect in the parent controller which is the edit to AuthorController that I suggested.  I will change my answer to be more specific.

Comment: So I need to inject $uibModalInstance in my BookController if I do so then my controller not working when i am calling its function from its own views

Comment: What do you mean "calling it from its own views"?

Comment: Means when i call the function "AddNew" from BookController it could not find the $uibModalInstance dependency.Giving this error:Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance

Comment: $uibModalInstance needs to be injected into BookController not AuthorController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108816/discussion-between-user2517610-and-jbrown).

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast a event (or use custom factory for books generation)

In BookController:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("newBook", book.id);
```

And in AuthorController:

```
$rootScope.$on("newBook", function(event, bookId){
    //do something
});
```

**Don't forget:** include $rootScope

Comment: but how can i differentiate that the call is from BookController or AuthorController as I need to redirect to book list page when call coming from BookController?